# Multiple IF statements using dates and blank cells

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I currently have a spreadsheet showing when work needs to be complete by (Finish No later than - N2) and the date it was completed by (Actual Finish Date - L2). In the formula I have written it will bring back the words Non Compliant or Compliant if the Actual Finish date was before or after the Finish No later than.

=IF(N2>$L$2,"Non Compliant - Complete","Compliant - Complete")

This works fine but I also need to add two further words based on whether there is any date in the Actual Finish Date column.

Can someone help me add an extra If function to the end of mine with following rules?

If the date is blank and the Finish No later than date is before today then it returns  - Non Compliant - Open
or
If the date is blank and the Finish No later than date is grater than or equal to  today then it returns  - Compliant - Open

Thank you for looking

Comment: It's not clear what data you have and what you expect for different cases by the explanation given in text. In your formula you reference `$L$2` (cell reference) while in your explanation you reference the column. If you want us to help, please give actual data and example results. In general `IF` can be combined with `AND` or `OR`, but you could also use an array-formula using `*` or `+` respectively for example: `= IF((arraycondition1)*(arraycondition2),option1,option2)`

Comment: This just my guess as I understand that your date are in cell L2 and cell N2 and you just need something to work on like this in cell O2 = =IF(AND(L3="",N3=""),"",IF(N3<NOW(),"Non-Compliant-Open","Compliant-Open")) maybe you can a bit idea of your formula. But still your question need to be clarified.